# how to check if package with specified version is available?

Tags: python, pip

For example function `available('foobar>=1.1')` should check that package `foobar` is installed and its version is >= 1.1.

- There is `importlib.util.find_spec`, which can check whether module is installed.
- and `LooseVersion` from `distutils.version` to compare versions

But how can I parser string like `foobar>=1.1` and split it into module, version and comparator?

Or, what is more interesting, maybe there is already some standard way to do all these stuff at the same time? `pip` is probably doing the same thing when it reads packages from `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following if this helps:

```
import pkg_resources
my_packages = list(pkg_resources.find_distributions("C:/python27/lib/site-packages"))
version_string = my_packages[0].version

In [24]: print(my_packages[0])
zc.buildout 2.9.4
In [25]: my_packages[0]
Out[25]: '2.9.4'
```

The requirements functionality is implemented in pkg_resource in this fairly huge document:

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

For instance the following checks whether or not the packages are available and provides an exception if they are not

```
In [31]: pkg_resources.require('zc.buildout == 2.9.4')
Out[31]:
[zc.buildout 2.9.4 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages),
 setuptools 40.6.2 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages)]
```

To parse the name of a requirements you can use pkg_resources.parse_requirements this will give you the version and the module name and the comparator used.

```
require = list(pkg_resources.parse_requirements("zc.buildout == 2.9.4"))[0]
print(require.name)
'zc.buildout'
print(require.specs)
 [('==', '2.9.4')]
```

For the function which you wish to write you can do the following, Note this does not check if the package is available or not.

```
def split_package_requirement(package_string='foobar>=1.1'):
    """Splits the requirement into, name, comparator and version."""
    requirement = next(pkg_resources.parse_requirements("zc.buildout == 2.9.4"))
    comparator, version = requirement.specs[0]

    return requirement.name, comparator, version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for parsing module name and version

```
line = 'foobar>=1.1'
def f(line):

  i = line.find('=')
  if i!=-1:
    if line[i+1]!='=':
        i=i-1
    return line[:i],line[i+2:]
  else:
    return line,''
```

Output:

```
('foobar', '1.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the subprocess module (Security concerns)
There is a way that depends on the output of pip list.

### Simple way to check existence and minimum version

```py
import sys
import subprocess
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

def available(desired_package, min_version):
    packages = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'list']).decode().split('\n')[2:-1] # First 2 lines, and last line are not packages
    package_version = [package.split() for package in packages]

    package_dict = {}
    for package, version in package_version:
        package_dict[package] = version

    try: 
        if LooseVersion(package_dict[desired_package]) >= LooseVersion(min_version):
            print('Minimum version requirement met')
        else:
            print('Minimum version requirement not met')
    except KeyError:
            print('{} not found.'.format(desired_package))
```

```sh
>>> available('tensorflow', '0.0.1')
Minimum version requirement met
>>> available('tensorflow', '20.0.1')
Minimum version requirement not met
>>> available('tensorflowasd', '20.0.1')
tensorflowasd not found.
```

### More complicated way if exact comparison needs to be done from an input: "tensorflow>1.13.0"

```py
import sys
import subprocess
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
import re

def available(input):
    def version_comparer(version, desired_version, comparator):
        if comparator == '<=': return LooseVersion(version) <= LooseVersion(desired_version)
        elif comparator == '>=': return LooseVersion(version) >= LooseVersion(desired_version)
        elif comparator == '==': return LooseVersion(version) == LooseVersion(desired_version)
        elif comparator == '>': return LooseVersion(version) > LooseVersion(desired_version)
        elif comparator == '<': return LooseVersion(version) < LooseVersion(desired_version)
        else:
            print('Unexpected comparator')
            exit(1)

    match = re.match('([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)([^A-Za-z0-9-_]+)([\d\.]+$)', input)
    desired_package, comparator, desired_version = match[1], match[2], match[3]

    packages = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'list']).decode().split('\n')[2:-1] # First 2 lines, and last line are not packages
    package_version = [package.split() for package in packages]

    package_dict = {}
    for package, version in package_version:
        package_dict[package] = version
    try: 
        if version_comparer(package_dict[desired_package], desired_version, comparator):
            print('Input validated')
        else:
            print('Package exists, but requirement not met')
    except KeyError:
        print('{} not found.'.format(desired_package))
```

```sh
>>> available('tensorflow<0.0.1')
Package exists, but requirement not met
>>> available('tensorflowasd<0.0.1')
tensorflowasd not found.
>>> available('tensorflow>0.0.1')
Input validated
```